# Print String in decreasing length

Tags: python, string, for-loop

I am a beginner in python so please bear with me here.

I am trying to get following output:

Input: `apple`

Output:

```
apple
appl
app
ap
a
```

What I've tried:

```
b = raw_input("Enter the String")
for n in reversed(range(len(b)-1):
    print b[0:n]
```

I am getting syntax error in for loop. Need help.

Comment: Have you tried counting your parentheses?

Comment: Take a GOOD look at your traceback

Comment: I don't think you really want us to "bare" with you. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use negative indexes and avoid reversing the string

```
b = raw_input("Enter the String")
print b 
for i in range(1, len(b)):
    print b[:-i]
```

Comment: If I need to read the strings from the text file what modifications should I make in the above program ?

Comment: You can put the code below the first line into a function and call it passing the strings.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing a required `)` at the end of your `for` loop

```
for n in reversed(range(len(b)-1)): #<- two parenthesis before the colon
```